# Bracket around some (not all) lines in an equation

Tags: math-mode, align, amsmath, brackets

I want to put a bracket around some lines of an equation and add some text to it. It should look like this:

[image: what I want]

so the `:` of the texts should be aligned as well as the `=`.
I tried this code:

```
\begin{equation} 
\begin{aligned}
     \text{text1:} & \left\{ 
     \begin{aligned}
          a &=b+c\\ 
          d &=e+f 
     \end{aligned} \right.\\ 
     \text{text2:} & x=y+z 
\end{aligned} 
\end{equation}
```

But this leads to:

[image: what I have]

so the problem is that the `=`s are not aligned. I tried to add or remove some of the `&`, but nothing leads to a perfect alignment and I want to avoid doing a dirty workaround with `\quad` or similar.

Do you have an idea how to accomplish that?

Thanks for your help

Comment: See the `cases` environment of the `amsmath` package.  Also, the use of `\phantom` could help here.

Comment: `\phantom` enables me to have the correct alignment. Thanks! But then I have a big gab between the bracket and the formula. The `cases` environment showed the same results. Do you have a hint how to prevent that gap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I use a `tabstackengine` approach, on the theory that it allows me to control vertical distances between items precisely.  However, the `1.53` in the stackgap setting should, *in theory*, have been 1.5 exactly.  I think the issue is related to how big the `\left\{` is made, which in the default LaTeX font, is not purely scalable (see **ADDENDUM**).

The `\stackskip` definition is a user setting for the baselineskip between equation lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} 
     \def\stacktype{L}
     \def\stackskip{\dimexpr1.3\baselineskip}
     \setstackgap{L}{1.53\stackskip}
     \Centerstack[l]{text1:$\left\{\rule{0pt}{\stackskip}\right.$\\text2:}  
     \setstackgap{L}{\stackskip}
     \ensurestackMath{\alignCenterstack{
       a =& b+c\\ 
       d =& e+f\\
       x =& y+z 
     }} 
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The equation number will be aligned with the 2nd row:

[image]

**ADDENDUM**

As suspected, the issue is with the brace size.  If I vertically scale a brace to the exact desired size, then the alignment works perfectly with the `1.5` value in the stacking gap, regardless of how big the `\stackskip` is set:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine,scalerel}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} 
     \def\stacktype{L}
     \def\stackskip{\dimexpr1.3\baselineskip}
     \setstackgap{L}{1.5\stackskip}
     \Centerstack[l]{text1:{\raisebox{.5\dimexpr\ht\strutbox-\dp\strutbox}{%
       \scaleto[2.5ex]{\raisebox{-.5\dimexpr\ht\strutbox-\dp\strutbox}{\Bigg\{}}{%
         \dimexpr\stackskip+\baselineskip}}}\\text2:}
     \setstackgap{L}{\stackskip}
     \ensurestackMath{\alignCenterstack{
       a =& b+c\\ 
       d =& e+f\\
       x =& y+z 
     }} 
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A solution with `blkarray` and `eqparbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, blkarray}
\usepackage{eqparbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{blockarray}{lc@{{}={}}c}
    \begin{block}{\BAmultirow{\eqboxwidth{T}}\{c@{{}={}}c}
      \eqparbox{T}{Text text 1:}            &    a &b+c\\
      & d &e+f \\
    \end{block}
    \begin{block}{lc@{{}={}}c}
      \eqparbox{T}{Text 2:}  &    x &y+z \\
    \end{block}
  \end{blockarray}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]