# Equation system with specific form

Tags: equations, arrays, brackets

I am having trouble finding a way of writing this. I have tried align but can't get the bracket look like that. Any help is appreciated

[image: equation system]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Here's a [related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/320375/134805).

Comment: Also, see the `cancel` package for term strike-throughs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this could help ...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*} 
   &\begin{cases}
     \cancel{-12x}+6y=-42 \\
     \phantom{.}\underline{\cancel{12x}+16y=-24}
    \end{cases}\\
   &\phantom{12x+16.}22y=-66
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here I use some tabbed-stacks, in conjunction with `aligned`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cancel,tabstackengine,amsmath}
\TABstackMath
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\left\{
\tabbedCenterstack[r]{
  \cancel{-12x} +& 6y \\
  \underline{\phantom{y}\cancel{12x} +{}}
  &\underline{16y}
}
\right.\!
&
\tabbedCenterstack[l]{
  {}= -42\\
  \underline{\vphantom{y}= -24}}\\[-3pt]
22y  &= -66
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]